# UIPageViewController wont refresh UITableViewControllers

Tags: swift, uipageviewcontroller

Have a controller, we'll call it Bob, as a modal and it contains some labels and a UIPageViewController that loads 2 table controllers. The first time the page controller loads it loads the table controllers with all the correct data. Whenever Bob is opened again the table controllers data does not change. Bob's labels do change so it is receiving different requests from it's parent.

pageController is the name of the UIPageViewController

I've tried doing the following in the datasource section for the pageController

```
pageController.dataSource = nil
pageController.dataSource = self
```

but it didn't work. I've also tried setting the controller again after the new data is loaded and that didn't work either

```
pageController.setViewControllers([viewController(At: 0)!], direction: .forward, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

In the table controllers they are set to refresh their data like so and this is called after the new data is passed to them. I've verified that this is called whenever Bob is opened.

```
DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: { () -> Void in
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    })
```

I've also tried recreating the UIPageViewController altogether and that didn't work either.

I'm really stumped as to how to get the page controller to reload the table controllers with the new data.  I don't think the issue is at the table controllers but I'm open to trying anything. Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

So the cause wasn't any of what I had listed. Go figure. Instead it was how I was defining the table controllers. I was setting the value they where to use for loading when I was defining the controller and not at the time of when I load it.

So

```
private lazy var thatTableViewController: ThatTableViewController = {
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "ModalsStoryBoard", bundle: Bundle.main)
    var viewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ThatTableViewController") as! ThatTableViewController
    viewController.view.tag = 0
    return viewController
}()
```

used to also have a line like so

```
viewController.controller = Controller(id: self.markerId, activeController: .Problem)
```

Controller is a custom struct that I was passing. But by setting this at the same level as where the variable thatTableViewController is defined it would not change between calls since it was cached. So moving the

```
viewController.controller = Controller(id: self.markerId, activeController: .Problem)
```

outside the definition part, allowed it get changed and not cached.

This then allowed me to remove

```
pageController.dataSource = nil
pageController.dataSource = self
```

since the data is defined at the time that I get the controller that I want to load and not predefined.

Hopefully, this will help someone else to not do the same thing I did and set any values you need the other controllers to use to be defined not when you define the controller but later on when you need to use the controller.